# Restangular GET with paging parameters

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I have a rest endpoint that supports HAL and returns a JSON `Object` rather than an `Array`, for this reason I am using the following Restangular call:

```
var endpoint = Restangular.oneUrl('/transmissions/');
endpoint.get().then(doStuffWithData());
```

when I do `/transmissions?page=0&size=20` from the browser this actually affects the **content** element of the HAL JSON object.

How would I modify the above url to include pagination parameters. I have done the following but it doesnt work:

```
    var endpoint = Restangular.oneUrl('transmissions/', {
        page: $scope.page,
        size: $scope.size
    });
```

I get the following error

```
http://localhost:7001/myApp/transmissions/%5Bobject%20Object%5D
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to specify the query parameters on the 'get' method call:

```
var endpoint = Restangular.oneUrl('/transmissions/');
endpoint.get({
    page: $scope.page,
    size: $scope.size
}).then(doStuffWithData());
```

Or use setDefaultRequestParams, when you need to send these all the time.